# process maker 3.2 install in windows 10

Tags: installation, processmaker

When installing the processmaker 3.2 on windows 10 at the installation step, installing progress Bar dose not complete and installing not finish and No errors are displayed
what do I do??

Comment: check you system logs

Comment: Are you using the bitnami installation?